# Exponential equation+derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponentiation, exponential-function

I saw here on math.stackexchange.com an equation which has very nice solutions (by solutions I mean a proof):
$3^x+28^x=8^x+27^x$, where $x$ is a real number. However, I think there must be an elementary solution. Has someone an idea? Maybe considering a function and seeing how the first derivative and second derivative behave. I think we should divide the equation with $3^x$ to work with strictly increasing functions. I know that x=0 and x=2 are solutions! They are also the only ones! Ther exists a proof using the rules of Descartes and one simply on geneal case. Is there anothr way to prove the solutions are only 0 and 2? I don't know why but my question was erased...

Comment: This question is posted here yesterdey.

Comment: $x=2$ is a solution.

Comment: See also: See also: [Solve $3^x + 28^x=8^x+27^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581947)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $0$ is a solution for. 
We can observe that the equation can be transformed like
$$3^x+3^{x\log_328} = 3^{x\log_38}+3^{3x}$$
I'm trying to do something with this idea...
Ok, let's go!

Observe that $3^x+3^{x\log_328} \sim 3^x+3^{x\log_327} = 3^{4x}$ and that $3^{x\log_38}+3^{3x} \sim 3^{2x}+3^{3x}=3^{5x}$ when $x$ tends to + infinity. Take the function
$$f(x) =3^{-x}$$and notice that $$f(x) \sim 3^x+3^{x\log_328} - 3^{x\log_38}-3^{3x}$$
$f$ is estrictly decreasing on $(2, \infty)$. I believe that this is the reason for no more solutions that $0$ and $2$.

Comment: Hey! I know the solutions. I asked if there exists another way to prove that they are the only?