# Number of real roots of $3^x+4^x=2^x+5^x$ with proof

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, alternative-proof, karamata-inequality

This equation 
$$3^x+4^x=2^x+5^x$$
has two obvious real roots. The question is if it has more real roots than two. A proof is required in any case.

Comment: By Laguerre's "Generalized Descartes' rule of signs", the equation has at most 2 roots. Since you find two real roots. It is all it has. For a proof, see refs in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/800395/59379) many years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(t)=t^x.$

1. $x>1$ or $x<0$.

Since $f$ is a convex non-linear function and $(5,2)\succ(4,3),$ by Karamata we obtain:
$$f(5)+f(2)>f(4)+f(3)$$ or
$$5^x+2^x>4^x+3^x,$$ which says that in this case our equation has no roots.

2. $0<x<1.$

Here, $f$ is a concave function and by Karamata again we obtain:
$$5^x+2^x<4^x+3^x,$$ which says that in this case our equation has no roots.

But $1$ and $0$ are roots, which says that our equation has two roots exactly.

Answer (score 6):

We consider the equation
$$3^x+4^x=2^x+5^x~~~~(1)$$
Use Lagranges Mean Value Theorem (LMVT) for the function $f(t)=t^x$ for two intervals $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$. So 
$$\frac{3^x-2^x}{3-2}=xt_1^{x-1}, ~~~t_1 \in (2,3)~~~~(2)$$
and
$$\frac{5^x-4^x}{5-4}=xt_2^{x-1}, ~~~t_2 \in (4,5)~~~~(3).$$
By equating (2) and (3), we get (1) and 
$$xt_1^{x-1} = xt_2^{x-1}, ~~~t_1 \ne t_2\Rightarrow x=0~ \mbox{or}~ x=1.$$
Hence Eq. (1) can have only two real roots.

Comment: your answer makes sense, but why you are comparing slopes in the last equation?

Comment: @AjayMishra They are really just differences, since denominators are $1.$

Comment: Super Answer!!! One of the nicest answers I have read - Thank you.

Comment: @Nochance Thanks, though this question was declared Duplicate, yet people took an interest in its present solutions.